# using executable in Liquibase changesets

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, liquibase

I am using execute command tag from my liquibase changesets and this inturn is configured to run the sqls in oracle instant client sql plus. 
when i run a liquibase update on my changelogxml everything works fine and the liquibase update is sucessfull.I can see the changes to the table also. 
But when i try to fail the update process by giving a syntax error in my sql file refered in the changeset.Liquibase still returns liquibase update sucessfull.I expected it to throw sql errors.The sql when run seperately in toad throws syntax error.What should i do to get the error displayed out.?

Answer (score 0):

Datical has created a custom Liquibase change tag that executes SQL using the sqlplus command line client. It was surprisingly much more complicated that you might think.

Some of the issues we had to deal with:

- we had to do things to ensure that the sql files always had certain statements in place, and never had certain other statements. This might include things like setting the schema, ensuring that the only spool commands were ones we knew about, that the script had an 'EXIT' command, and ensuring that whenever there was a SQL error that the exit code was returned.
- The sqlplus executable does not return an exit code (i.e. a non-zero exit code form the native process) in all cases, and instead will write errors to an error table in the database. The table where sqlplus writes errors is called `sperrorlog`, and this may be what you will need to look into.

I can't really go into all the details, but just know that what you are attempting to do is neither simple nor straightforward.

Comment: Steve i tried the logLevel=info and this for now seems to address my issue ,but yes i did indeed looked into what you said.One question i have is even if i query sperrorlog after setting it on.It requires a commit to have the error logged into the table , does that mean we need to explicitly execute commit from liquibase?i tried by even setting auto commit but it still expects a commit to have the error logged to sperror table.any work arounds ?